# Java Oracle connection - Connection has already been closed

Tags: java, database-connection, weblogic, connection-pooling, connection-timeout

I simplify the code as below:

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();

UserTransaction ut = util.getTransaction();

// ut.begin();
for (xxx) { // heavy for-loop, a lot of records

    ut.begin();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); // very fast sql update
    pstmt.executeUpdate();  
    pstmt.close();
    ut.commit();

}
//ut.commit();
```

As the code above, the `for-loop` will be running very long, around 1-2 hour.

Last time, when I put the `begin` and `commit` outside of `for-loop`, I encounter an error in the end of loop:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection timed out
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1065)
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
```

Then I realize, system not able to commit because in this case, `UserTransaction` maybe already timeout. (error throw at the `ut.commit()`)

So I move the `begin` and `commit` into the `for-loop` to avoid the issue, but I got another error in somewhere around 1 hour and half:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.checkConnection(PoolConnection.java:62)
   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.preInvocationHandler(Connection.java:100)
   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:553)
```

My code is single threaded, so I am very sure, there is no other thread that close the `conn` connection. (this time the error throw at `conn.prepareStatement(sql)`)

And due to the `for-loop`, the connection is not idle, because it keep doing `update` and `commit`. How can a connection auto-closed (due to whatever reason? timeout?)?

So what happen to the connection? I searched but can't find any timeout settings like connection's pool borrow timeout or blah blah blah.

Anyone has idea?

Comment: What is `util`? Also when posting stack traces POST THE COMPLETE STACK TRACE and indicate which statement in your code throws.  Also, tell us on which iteration of the loop the error occurs: 1st, second, 1000th?

Comment: Can you try removing pstmt.close();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941889/java-sql-sqlexception-connection-has-already-been-closed)